# Z-Index and Relative/Absolute Positioning

Tags: css, z-index, positioning

I'm having some problems with z-index and positioning. Basically, when you hover over the menu items (home, about etc), paint splashes should load underneath the menu:

http://www.saradouglas.net/home

[Stylesheet is located here](http://www.saradouglas.net/wp-content/themes/sara-douglas-theme/style.css).

This worked fine when each splash div was set to absolute positioning, but I realised that these would appear in different places in different screen resolutions. I thought it would just be a case of changing this to relative positioning, and then adjusting the co-ordinates accordingly. Unfortunately now my splashes don't appear under the menu, like they should.

To clarify, I want the splashes to appear under the menu - so the menu should always appear on top of the splashes. This has only become a problem since setting the menu to relative, and these splashes to absolute.

I'm hoping this is a simple one to fix and I'm just missing something. I'm hoping someone here can tell me where I've gone wrong and offer a solution!

There have been some good answers submitted so far but unfortunately they have not fixed my problem. I have tried adding the menu background to the ul class rather than the div, but this has made no difference to the problem.

Comment: Which of the stylesheets are the paint splashes in?

Comment: http://www.saradouglas.net/wp-content/themes/sara-douglas-theme/style.css

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but general feedback. I'd recommend to load the background of these `spans` at once... right now after a user hovers a menu item their browser makes a request for the image... simply move the `background` property to `spans` not to `a:hover span`... thus all the images will be loaded at once.

Comment: Thanks - I was planning on loading them all at once but wanted to figure this part out first. Thanks for the feedback though, appreciated!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If I recall correctly the precedence order of z-indices is something like this:

- canvas (where the element is drawn / parents drawable area)
- bg images
- z-index: -1
- default (0)
- z-index: 1+

When you give any child element a `z-index` of -1, it won't go below the parent's background because of the parent's precedence.

Here is your solution (just tried on firebug and it works):

1. Remove the bg image from `#menu` and add a separate `div` under the `ul.menu` before the `li`'s.
2. Give the css below to this `div`.
3. Now give all those brush strokes a `z-index` smaller than -1. -2 works.

And that should be it.

**CSS:**

```
position:absolute;
top:0;
bottom:0;
left:0;
right:0;
z-index:-1;
background: url(...);
```

I know it's not that much semantic but, hey it works, right? :P

Comment: Hi - thanks for your answer and thank you especially for being so thorough. Unfortunately, I'm still having the same z-index problem! Would you be so kind to check if I've maybe missed something?

Comment: Yeah, add that #menu-separator inside the ul, not next to it as a sibling. #menu-separator should be a child of the ul.

Comment: Perfect. I just need to do some work on the ul now to make it look the way it was, but that's answered my question.. thank you!!

Comment: @rossautomatica glad I can help. Have a nice day! By the way I noticed that you're using a lot of images in there. I think it would be wise to use css sprites for that. Check out my answer here for more info if you're unfamiliar to the topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10119461/can-i-replace-an-image-tags-image-with-css/10120024#10120024

Answer (score 1):

You should set position relative in your menu div, then add absolute positioning divs in menu's div. then the different screen resolutions it isn't problem.

Comment: This answers my positioning problem, but now the splashes appear above the menu...

Comment: It's exactly the same :)

Comment: Thanks for your help - however, the splashes are appearing on top of the menu, but they should be underneath the menu. Do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: You can set it with top, right, left, and bottom atributes in css.

Comment: Is it not a problem with z-index though?

Comment: Items with position absolut must have heigher z-index then others.

Comment: So I can't have a relative item with z-index 5, and absolute with z index 4, for example? Will it just not work at all?

Comment: You have but then the relative items are under absolut items. If it is that what you want its work of corse.

Comment: I want the menu (relative) to be above the splashes (absolute).

Comment: So it's easy. You must set the relative menu the higher z-index and set top and left atributes of each absolute item. It work :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't understand.. I have the menu set to relative, and it has a higher z-index than my absolute items.. but the absolute items still appear on top of the menu. I would like to move the discussion to chat but I don't have a high enough reputation :(

Comment: I have looked on your code and I have other idea. You can try to positioning your menu without height of li. And then in css use `li:hover{ background-image: url(your url); background-repeat: no-repeat}` Do you know what I mean? It is better solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by simply setting bg, paddings and height on ul instead of `<div id="menu">`

Comment: Hi Simon, thanks for your answer. I tried that - I set the bg, paddings & height on the 'menu' ul instead of the div, but it gave me the exact same result I currently have. I've now reverted back to my original code, so I'm unfortunately no further forward. Perhaps I misunderstood your answer?