# div with higher z-index appears behind div with lower z-index

Tags: html, css

I have something like this

```
<div class="target" style="z-index: 4000;"></div>
<div class="token_source" style="z-index: 2000;">
    <div class="token" style="z-index: 10000;"></div>
</div>
```

Now I can drag token into target. When I drag token over target, token appears behind the target which is not right seeing how token's z-index is greater than target z-index. If I remove the token_source z-index then everything works fine. I know I am missing something very obvious here. Can anybody help me out ?

Comment: parent z-index, token_source takes precedence over child token.  so 2000 < 4000

Comment: I'm sure it has something to do with nesting inside a lower z-index

Comment: @Rooster thanks for the reply. How do I tell it to ignore parent z-index ?

Comment: You can't.   You have to revise the structure of the document.

Comment: @ShaggyInjun  You don't.  You either change the zindexes or restructure your html.

Comment: have you set CSS position to relative or absolute?

Comment: Why 10000? Do you have 10000 layers?

Comment: @ChrisCannon It's an example. 10000 is a valid number for z-index. The problem is an other.

Answer (score 2):

add position to your divs for example

```
.target,token_source,token{position:absolute;}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant in my question-comment. Maybe this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10322868/z-index-and-relative-absolute-positioning

Comment: @Abdul, thanks for the answer but that is really not an option. I am already using `position:absolute`, and if I add it to these divs it will break the view. Instead I have opted to remove the style on the token_source using javascript while the tokens are being dragged and then add them back once the dragging is complete.