# Put the div overlaping the image using CSS

Tags: html, css, css-position, overlap

I want to put the div above the image as shown in example image below.

Here is what I want to do. I just used paint for this.
[image]

here is the code I have tried, but its not working as I expected.
[image]

here is the code for the div and the image

```
 <img src="<?php echo $newsimage; ?>" alt="court" style="width:100%; height:430px;">
<div class="content">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
           <div class="fix midbar">
              <div class="viewnews">
                    <h3><?php echo $title; ?> </h3>
                     <p>Date posted: <?php echo $date; ?></p>
                     <p><?php echo $content; ?></p>
              </div>
           </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is the style of the div and the content

```
 .midbar{
  background:none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
  padding:19px;
  width: 850px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px #ccc;
  display:block;
  margin-left: 170px;
  margin-top:-150px;
  background-color: gray;


}


.content {
  min-height: 100%;
  /* equal to footer height */
  margin-bottom: 100px; 
}
.content:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: use z-index, for the image z-index:10; and for div z-index: 11; for-image you can also put the position: absolute; top:150px;

Comment: Use `position:relative` and `z-index:10` for `.midbar` class

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10322868/z-index-and-relative-absolute-positioning) gives a nice overview of your problem

Comment: Only thing you are missing is position: relative; in .midbar div  @nethken

Comment: @eirenaios how can i mark your answer as a correct answer?

Comment: @nethken just check the checkbox below the voting arrows!! thans!! http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @eirenaios there is no need for using the z-index lol. i dont know how z index works.

Comment: @this z-index is the stack of html elements in z axis; know more about it https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/

Comment: @nethken you have allready marked around 9 answer as the correct!! How can you be unaware after that?

Comment: @eirenaios thanks sir :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try position relative, margin in negative values and z-index greater than 1:

```
.midbar{
      position:relative;
      margin-top:-40px;
      z-index:10;

      background:none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
      padding:19px;
      width: 850px;
      box-shadow: 0 0 3px #ccc;
      display:block;
      margin-left: 170px;
      margin-top:-150px;
      background-color: gray;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I hope this should work.

```
    <div class="content">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">        
               <div class="fix midbar">
                  <div class="viewnews">
<img src="<?php echo $newsimage; ?>" alt="court" style="width:100%; height:430px;">
                        <h3><?php echo $title; ?> </h3>
                         <p>Date posted: <?php echo $date; ?></p>
                         <p><?php echo $content; ?></p>
                  </div>
               </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
.content {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 100px; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.content {
    background-color: gray;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `position:relative` and `z-index:10` for your class. Like this:

```
.midbar{
      position:relative;
      z-index:10;

      padding:19px;
      width: 850px;
      box-shadow: 0 0 3px #ccc;
      display:block;
      margin-left: 170px;
      margin-top:-150px;
      background-color: gray;
}
```